# Совместить Freemarker и Vue.js

Tags: java, vue.js, spring-mvc, spring-boot, freemarker

Есть MVC проект с использованием Freemarker. Стоит задача перевести на микросервисы. Для фронта был выбран Vue. Сразу столкнулся с проблемой, что в шаблонах ftl не работают директивы Vue вида {{ item }}.  Гугл ничем не помог. Собственно вопрос, возможно ли использование директив Vue в шаблонах, или нужно сразу переписывать весь фронт?

Comment: Если выделяете фронт в отдельное приложение, то выделяйте полностью, оставляете на сервере только API для доступа к данным.

Comment: Думал постепенно переписывать и в процессе использовать совместно. В конечном счете будут два отдельных приложения, но пока стоит вопрос совместного использования

Comment: Может Вы все-таки что-то не так делаете? Беглый гуглинг выдает кучу примеров, аналогичных Вашему. Можете привести пример?

Comment: Синтаксис вывода значений ftl-шаблона - ${ item }, а Vue - {{ item }}. Freemarker не понимает синтаксис Vue и выводит не значение item, а текст "{{ item }}". Я не знаю, как более подробно объяснить. Можно ли скинуть ссылку на пример, именно по этой проблеме ничего не нашел.